# Where does meteor install npm packages referenced in packages.json?

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, meteorite

After meteor installs npm packages:

```
npm: updating npm dependencies -- winston...
```

Npm.require results in module not found error, by inspecting the code and debugging via node-inspector, I discovered that putting a standard node_modules folder (installed via npm install) in .meteor folder in the root of my meteor app folder gets it to find it.

However when deploying to meteor.com or using any automated build-pack (like Heroku's) this might not be possible, I would rather have a scenario where I can link the automatically downloaded modules to the paths Npm.require looks in.

Any idea where it downloads the packages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **meteorite** packages this would be:

`/path/to/your/project/packages/package_name/.npm/package/node_modules/`

For core **meteor** packages I guess this is

`~/.meteor/packages/package_name/hash/npm/node_modules/`

Comment: This applies to packages, and it works correctly, what about directly using NPM modules directly in the code? Is this not supported? Worth noting is that Meteor parses packages.json in the root of my app, but I have no idea where it stores the packages.

Comment: Meteor stores the packages in a `.npm` directory (usually hidden) in the package directory that the npm module is used. I didn't think meteor parses `packages.json`, there is a project out there called demeteorizer which actually creates the package.json for you. Meteor looks for npm dependencies made with `Npm.depends` in the `package.js` files of projects.

Comment: I guess that's where my problem is, there's never a .npm directory in the app's root, not in Ubuntu, not in Ubuntu wrapped in Vagrant, not even in windows.